# Can I print a page from a string? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, printing

I have a variable that contains html code. example:

```
var htmlString = "<html><head></head><body><p>Sample text</p></body></html>"
```

Is it possible for me to print this string using window.print() or something along those lines? The goal is to have the print window pop up and give the user the option to print [the string that I have created.]

EDIT: I would like them to be able to print the generated webpage and NOT the plain text.

Comment: You could always open a popup, insert the HTML there, and add an onload-event for the page, so it would run `window.print()` in the popup

Comment: @NoLifeKing how would one do this?

Comment: @arcadeRob Follow the link that FSou1 posted. It shows how you can open a new popup and write the information into it and then print it.